# DID - Subgroup analysis

Tags: difference-in-difference

In a difference-in-differences analysis, what does it mean doing a subgroup analysis for example, on years of schooling?

- Compare treated individuals with higher education vs control individuals with higher education, or
- Compare treated individuals with higher education vs all control individuals?